# How to append text x number of times with each click event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Easiest example I can come up with is a neverending "You clicked" on the first click, then on the second, "You clicked again," and "You clicked again and again, " finally "You clicked again and again...n...and again."

So the first click is normal. Second appends "again". Each time after appends "and again".

I tried doing it with an increasing index but I can't figure out how to multiply a string like  it seems I would need to like:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).text("You clicked" + index++ + "");
```

But of course that will just return "You clicked 1" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/35uHB/

```
var clickCount = 0;
$('.theDiv').click(function() {
    var text = ["You clicked"];

    if (clickCount > 0) {
        text.push(" again");
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < clickCount; i++)
    {
        text.push(" and again");
    }
    text.push("!");

    clickCount++;

    $('.result').text(text.join(''));    

});
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to have an array like below and using it..

```
var myText = ['You clicked', ' again', ' and again'];
var ptr = 0;
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).text(function (i, v) {
        return (ptr == 0)?myText[ptr]:(v + myText[ptr]);
    });
    if (ptr < myText.length - 1) ptr++;
});
```

Using that array, you can control how many different message you want to append.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/x66sd/

Comment: i believe this is what OP requests.

Comment: I didn't see the new edits until now. Before it was returning undefined after the third click but now it appears to be working. Thanks.

Comment: @o_O Yea, I just wrote the code here without testing and missed few important stuff. Caught them while creating a demo. :)

Answer (score 3):

`$(this).text($(this).text() + " again");`

Most jQuery functions that manipulate the properties of an element can be used to both get and set the value of that property, e.g. `$elem.text()` gives you the current text value, `$elem.text(value)` sets it to `value`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var c = 0;
    $('button').click(function(){
        if(c == 0) {$(this).append(' again');c++;}
        else $(this).append(' and again')
    })

})
```

I suggest this instead of using `$(this).text()` twice. :)

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2rfm5/24/)**

Comment: +1 Append was what I was originally looking into and it would be a fine way to do it, however, @Jason P's answer seems to do exactly what I need.